# Show that there exists $n$ such that $i^n = 0$ for all $i$ in the ideal $I$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm new to this medium, but I'm quite stuck with an exercise so hopefully someone here can help me.

This is the exercise: 
Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $A$, and assume that for every $i\in I$ there exists an $n_i$ such that $i^{n_i} = 0$. Show that there is an $n$ such that $i^n = 0$ for every $i\in I$.

I thought about this:
$A$ is Noetherian so $I$ is finitely generated. That means, there exist $i_1, \ldots, i_m$ such that all of the elements in $I$ are linear combinations of $i_1, \ldots, i_m$. 
Now is it possible to take $n = n_1n_2\cdots n_m$?

I was thinking, maybe I have to use something like this: $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$. This holds in a field of characteristic $p$. If this is true, then indeed $(a_1i_1 + \ldots + a_mi_m)^n = 0 + \ldots + 0 = 0.$

Answer (score 9):

Hint : Use multinomial theorem to see that the following is true $$(a_1i_1+\cdots +a_mi_m)^{n_1+\cdots +n_m}=0$$

Comment: What if $A$ is not commutative?

Comment: Since one of the tags is commutative-algebra, I think the OP probably just forgot to include the assumption that $A$ is in fact commutative.

Comment: Nice: +1, pritam. You can even take the smaller exponent $n_1+\cdots +n_m-m+1$ (but this is an essentially useless "amelioration"...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, the answer is, as usual, less complicated than I imagined. Why didn't I come up with this myself? ;) And excuse me, in the course I follow we always assume rings are commutative and have an identity so I forgot to mention it.

Comment: You can also use induction by $m$ the number of generators of $I$, and just the binomial theorem, but this is basically the same proof.

Answer (score 3):

Pritam's binomial approach is the easiest way to solve this problem in the commutative setting. In case you're interested though, it's also true in the noncommutative setting.

[Levitzky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitzky%27s_theorem) says that any nil right ideal in a right Noetherian ring is nilpotent. This implies your conclusion (in fact, even more.) However this is not as elementary as the binomial proof in the commutative case :)